# Windows 11 Python can't update pip

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, pip

When I try to update pip on VS Code and also on cmd,
[This appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o54C8.png) and I have no idea why.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled pip and Python 3 times now. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you run the indicated command?

Comment: _Help would be appreciated_ The message literally tells you what command to run.  What more help do you need?

Comment: I have run the command, it executed correctly, but it didn't update

Comment: Please dont post images of screen output. Copy/Paste the text into your question instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I had to run

```
pip config set global.user false
```

and then do the upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the command suggested by pip itself?
"To update, run: **python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip**"
Just paste it into cmd.

Comment: Yes, and the result is in the image.

Comment: In your image, it looks like you're already running the latest version of pip (22.2.2). What does pip -V output ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Run your Command Prompt as administrator
2. Copy/Paste the line below in the terminal and press `OK`

*C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip*

**Note** : Your Python installation folder may be different. Make sure to put the convenient path. You can get yours by running this code in any python interpreter :

```
import sys

locate_python = sys.exec_prefix

print(locate_python)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it had no effect.